# ng-class scope variable not working

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

I am trying to add CSS based on a scope variable in Angular JS:

```
<html>
<head>
    <style type="text/css">
        body {color: black; font-size: 10px;}
        .redcolor {color: red; font-size: 20px}
        .greencolor {color: green; font-size: 100px}
    </style>
</head>
<body ng-app="app">
    <div ng-controler="controller">
        <span ng-class="{redcolor: test1.isRed, greencolor: test1.isGreen}">Span1</span><br/><br/>
        <span ng-class="{redcolor: test2.isRed, greencolor: test2.isGreen}">Span2</span>
    </div>

    <script src="angular.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    angular.module('app',[])
    .controller('controler', function($scope) {
        $scope.test1 = {isRed: true, isGreen: false};
        $scope.test2 = {isRed: false, isGreen: true};
    });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

When I run this program it is just applying the CSS of body. I need span 1 with style of redColor and Span 2 with style of greenColor.

Please help me what is the issue in this code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are few issues with your code,

(i) It should be  **`ng-controller`** instead of  `ng-controler`

(ii) Also your controller name is **`controler`** not **`controller`**

Change it as follows,

```
 <div ng-controller="controler">    
 </div>
```

**DEMO**

```js
angular.module('app',[])
    .controller('controler', function($scope) {
        $scope.test1 = {isRed: true, isGreen: false};
        $scope.test2 = {isRed: false, isGreen: true};
    });
```

```html
<html>
<head>   
 <style type="text/css">
        body {color: black; font-size: 10px;}
        .redcolor {color: red; font-size: 20px}
        .greencolor {color: green; font-size: 100px}
  </style>
</head>
<body ng-app="app">
    <div ng-controller="controler">
          <span ng-class="{redcolor: test1.isRed, greencolor: test1.isGreen}">Span1</span><br/><br/>
    <span ng-class="{redcolor: test2.isRed, greencolor: test2.isGreen}">Span2</span>

    </div>
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.4/angular.js"></script>  
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you, I am using eclipse IDE for development so not able to find the basic mistakes. Can you please suggest a better IDE for developing AngularJS apps that can give suggestions and corrections.

Comment: You can use visual studio code and use the angular snippets and intellisence it will auto detect the errors for you

Comment: I am from Java background, so was using eclipse. Is Visual Studio code is free software, can I use it for my project?

Comment: yes you can use it for your project. if you need a light weight ide go for sublime text